# "that" in indirect speech

Tags: grammar, reported-speech, sentence-usage

In **indirect speech** it is more common for the reporting clause to come first. When the reporting clause is first, we don’t put a comma between the reporting clause and the reported clause.

She told me they had left her without any money.

NOT: She told me, they had left her without any money.

If we use "**that**", the sentence becomes: She told me **that** they had left her without any money.

NOT: She told me, **that** they had left her without any money.

When the reporting clause comes after the reported clause, we use a comma to separate the two parts:

They had left her without any money, She told me.

My doubt: Shall we use "**that**" in the beginning of reported clause?

**That** they had left her without any money, She told me.

Comment: There would never be a comma after that in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

"They had left her without any money, She told me." sounds a bit like something the character Yoda from Star Wars might say. So unless you're using it for comedic effect, you can't just put the reporting clause at the end like that without also changing from reported to direct speech, like:

> "They left me without any money", she told me.

You generally don't start sentences with "that" when it's used as a conjunction, such as in your example. There are exceptions to this in formal speech when you want to put emphasis on something, for example:

> **That** a nation requires a strict government to be prosperous is a myth dictators love.

This is the same as saying "dictators love the myth **that** a nation requires a strict government to be prosperous", but it places emphasis on the myth, rather than the dictators.

You could use this pattern to say:

> **That** they had left her without any money **was what** she told me.

This is correct, but sounds unusual, because you're using formal language to describe presumably something personal that someone has shared, which is not exactly a formal context.

Comment: Can we say like this: "Nobody had gone in or out during the previous hour, he informed us"?

Comment: @Nandy it sounds more natural to say "He informed us (that) nobody had gone in or out during the previous hour." If you really want to put "he informed us" at the end, you'd want to switch to direct speech - "Nobody has gone in or out in the last/past hour", he informed us. Note that you'd have to put the direct speech clause in quotes, like I did with the other example in my answer.

Comment: If you don't mind could you please look at this link: https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/reported-speech_2

Comment: Could you tell me now?

Comment: I've looked at the link - do you have a specific question about it?

Comment: Yes. If the reporting clause comes after the reported clause what about "that" then?

Comment: Even on the website you've linked, there is a warning that it's more common for the reporting clause to come first. But if you really, really want to put the reporting clause at the end, you can't just start your sentence with "That + reported clause". This article from the same website shows the expected use of a that-clause: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns-verb-that-clause